# Finding the longest repeating substring with suffix arrays

Tags: python, suffix-array

I found an implementation of suffix arrays [here](https://github.com/benfulton/Algorithmic-Alley/blob/master/AlgorithmicAlley/SuffixArrays/sa.py) (not sure if it's the most efficient so if there's any better I'd be glad to know).

For a given string:

```python
data = '1034408'*10
```

It generates the following suffix array:

```python
suffix_array = [64, 57, 50, 43, 36, 29, 22, 15, 8, 1, 68, 61, 54, 47, 40, 33, 26, 19, 12, 5, 63, 56, 49, 42, 35, 28, 21, 14, 7, 0, 65, 58, 51, 44, 37, 30, 23, 16, 9, 2, 67, 60, 53, 46, 39, 32, 25, 18, 11, 4, 66, 59, 52, 45, 38, 31, 24, 17, 10, 3, 69, 62, 55, 48, 41, 34, 27, 20, 13, 6]
```

Having:

```python
len(suffix_array) = 70
max(suffix_array) = 69
suffix_array.index(max(suffix_array)) = 60
```

Is a suffix tree better suited for this task?

Comment: As you can see in the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem a suffix tree can be used for this task (to solve it optimally). I don't really know a lot about suffix arrays, but from what I understand, if you can use it to solve the question in $O(n)$ time, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: "Better" by what criteria?  I don't see the task described in the body of the post.

Comment: @D.W. more efficient (both temporal and spatial).

Comment: This might be hard to answer in a useful way.  They have the same asymptotic efficiency.  Constant factors are hard to analyze as they depend on the architecture.  It's not clear to me which of those you are asking about.